# how to transform sub views along with main view in landscape mode

Tags: iphone

i am crating an application.

That contains one main view and 4 subviews.

i add all these 4 views as subview with their respected button actions.

Now i need to support my application to both land scape and portrayed.

when ever i rotate my simulator from portrayed  to land scape sub view are not rotated.

it will shown like this.  [link1](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e12ac619c2.gif),[link2](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d2b2371cd8.gif)

some where i found we need to transform our self when device detect rotation.

i did n't find how can i,

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to implement
`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`
and return YES for all supported orientations.

Then you either implement `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` and setup you subviews' properties accordingly or specify proper `autoresizingMask` for the subviews

Comment: - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
 test.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
} i am trying this but there is no result

Comment: you don't specify autoresizingMasks in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration, you change the frames (usually). post your code please